# Retrieve data from localhost

Tags: php, mysql

[View material_master table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCTAt.png)

I would like to retrieve the material_price and quantity from material_master table (refer to picture), after which I want to multiply and add the cost together.

Example:

```
(For Table Top) --> 10*1=10 

(For Legs) --> 4*4=16

 Total = 10+4=$26.
```

How do I execute it in query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This:

```
SELECT SUM(material_price*quantity) as TotalPrice, 
material_price_master_id,
material_name 
FROM material_master 
GROUP BY material_price_master_id
```

It will also work without using SUM function as well

Comment: Is the way to echo the result?

<?php
session_start();

// include a php file that contains the common database connection codes
include ("dbFunctions.php");

$query = "SELECT
    SUM(tmp.cost_sum) AS total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            material_price * quantity as cost_sum
        FROM
            material_master
        GROUP BY
            material_master_id
    ) AS tmp";

// execute the query
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>


<td>Total Material Cost = <?php echo $row['material_price']; ?> <p></td>

Comment: @Janice: you are going right, just little changes required for reference please check.http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_free_result.asp

Comment: @Janice: if you still face an issue let me know, and one more thing, i think you are new on SO, kindly accept the best answer by using left green tick. this will help full for others.

Comment: Hi, I have another question. I would like to echo the quantity for table top and legs respectively. 

right now this is my code which only echo the number 1.

`<p align="left">Total quantity of Table Tops: <?php echo $quantity; ?></p>
<p align="left">Total quantity of Table Legs: <?php echo $quantity; ?></p>`

How do I echo for Table Top should be 1, Legs should be 4?